# CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"members\" (type string) at path \"_id\" for model \"Group\"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, rest

I am developing a website in MERN stack. I am getting error when I was developing an API in back-end.

```
{
  "stringValue": "\"members\"",
  "valueType": "string",
  "kind": "ObjectId",
  "value": "members",
  "path": "_id",
  "reason": {},
  "name": "CastError",
  "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"members\" (type string) at path \"_id\" for model \"Group\""
}
```

[image: Click here to see the error picture]

I am getting this castError.

My route function looks like this

```
const getMembersList = async(req, res)=>{
    res.status(200).json("OK")
}
```

[image: Can see click here for the image]

```
// get members list of a group
router.get("/members", groupMethod.getMembersList)
```

This is the route URL definition

I am not understanding why I am getting this error.
I tried to debug it with other possibilities, here's what I found:

- instead of `members` anything written same error
- but if I define my route like this `router.get('/members/<anything here: params or simple text> , groupMethod.getMembersList)` the API call is happening.

I was expecting the API route will work like this and I will be able to fetch the required data.

Comment: Please do not post code in images, edit your question to remove the images and post the code itself.